# i have error "Instance of 'Resource' has no 'spreadsheets' memberpylint(no-member)"

Tags: google-sheets-api

i update all module. but encounter this error "Instance of 'Resource' has no 'spreadsheets' memberpylint(no-member)"

help me plz

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh0Cm.png)

Comment: It should be `service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)`. How is `sv` defined?

Comment: @ ziganotschka sv is google spreadsheet api's service

`from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient import discovery
sv = discovery.build('sheets','v4',credentials=creds)`